# Asp.net MVC How to send data from HTML Color picker to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one page with below html, its a series of color pickers, the thing I dont know is how to pick these values on the controller action.

I am using jquery plugin:
http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

My controller so far is like this

```
public class CustomizeController : Controller
{
// GET: Customize
public ActionResult Index()
{
    User spUser = null;

    var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

    using (var cc = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
    {
        int aprovisionado = (int)cc.Web.GetPropertyBagValueInt("Vinculosc.PlantillasIntranet.Aprovisionado", 0);
        if (aprovisionado == 0)
        {
            string libraryName = "ConfiguraciónColores";
            Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            fields.Add("Color1", "Text");
            fields.Add("Color2", "Text");
            fields.Add("Color3", "Text");
            fields.Add("Color4", "Text");
            fields.Add("Color5", "Text");
            //ProvisionTemplate(cc);
            CreateLibrary(cc, libraryName);
            AddFields(cc, libraryName, fields);
        }
    }
    #region comments
    /*Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostURL"]);

    using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity)) 
    {
        var web = clientContext.Web;

        clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Lists.Include(l => l.Title).Where(l => !l.hidden));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        return View(web.Lists);
    }*/
    #endregion

    return View();
}
```

My view is like this

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage2.cshtml";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" id="stylesheet">Hojas de estilos</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="selCssFile" onchange="selChange(this.value)">
                <option></option>
                <option value="c">Crear Nuevo</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                <option value="1">3</option>
                <option value="1">4</option>
            </select>
            <span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFileName" style="display:none;" placeholder="Nombre del archivo">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Color base, links, botones, borde encabezado y pie
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="colorSelector" class="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Fondo de la pagina, fondo de los cuadros
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="colorSelector2" class="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Navegación
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="colorSelector3" class="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Navegación (Item seleccionado)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="colorSelector4" class="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Pie de página
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="colorSelector5" class="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="buttons">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar y aplicar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I need to know is how to retrieve those values on the server side so I can save them to a database or something

Comment: Do you have script that initializes color pickers?

Comment: Do you have a model that goes along with your view?  You'll want one to be able to _"retrieve those values on the server side"_

Comment: There is a lot of code in your controller, but how it's connected to the view? Your view seems to be pure HTML without any MVC stuff.